# Your Devices Software is out of Date adware

Tags: malware, ads

I keep getting popups from everywhere taking me to the play store saying I need to download Super File Manager. I recently installed an APK from the web. I knew it was a virus after I installed. The app doesn't show in the "apps" section in settings. Im trying to uninstall it, but I can't find anything. On a Moto z unlocked Android 6.0.1

Comment: It detects nothing even after I install it and waited for another pop-up. Btw it's not a toast, it's a full screen ad

Comment: @beeshyams Kaspersky didn't work. I'll try malwarebytes

Comment: Good. You can post that as answer